# Install fail for Maven 3.0.4

Tags: maven, installation

CentOS with java 1.4.2 and ant 1.6.5

1. Download maven 3.0.4 source
2. export M2_HOME=$HOME/maven/
3. ant

I then get following log. Couldn't find anything on google. Suggestions appreciated.

```
Buildfile: build.xml

clean-bootstrap:

initTaskDefs:
     [echo] Building Apache Maven ...

isMavenHomeSet:

init:
     [echo] maven.home = /home/larryk/maven/
     [echo] maven.repo.local = /home/larryk/.m2/repository
     [echo] distributionId = apache-maven
     [echo] distributionName = Apache Maven
     [echo] distributionDirectory = apache-maven

prompt-maven-home-exists:

pull:
[artifact:pom] -----------------------------------------------------
[artifact:pom] this realm = plexus.core
[artifact:pom] Number of imports: 0
[artifact:pom] -----------------------------------------------------
[artifact:pom] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
[artifact:pom]  Diagnosis:
[artifact:pom]
[artifact:pom] Unable to find component: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectBuilder
[artifact:pom] java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue

BUILD FAILED
/home/downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4/build.xml:105: Unable to find component: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectBuilder

Total time: 1 second
```

**Added**

Thanks to @sparc_speed, I found the problem.

First issue was to upgrade to current Java. I used yum to automatically update the system. That brought me Java 1.6. Unfortunately that didn't solve the build problem--exact same error as before.

Turns out that yum had updated Java to 1.6. But yum didn't automatically upgrade the libraries. After the yum upgrade, these packages were on the system:

```
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat.i386
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-devel.i386
java-1.6.0-openjdk.i386
```

Answer was to manually use yum to install the latest libraries:

`sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.i386`

Note that maven still doesn't build:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4/build.xml:228: Syntax error in property: ${
```

but that's their problem, I'll file a bug with them.

**Ant 1.8+ required** Looks like the build error is a [doc error](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGSITE-147) that was fixed on the maven website but not in the project's `README.bootstrap.txt` file.

I'll file a bug against the readme file.

**[Bug report filed](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5270)**

Comment: Why are you build Maven from source and not using any existing archive ? http://maven.apache.org/download.html

Comment: I usually build from source and usually don't have a problem doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you were using Java 1.4 - you probably need to upgrade.  It would seem from this error message that Maven 3.0 needs `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`, which was first added to Java in 1.5

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded to Java 1.6.0_22 but the error message is still the same. Sigh.

Comment: Sorry to hear! Try digging into the ant code. From what I could tell the `<artifact:pom>` ant task is a custom Maven ant task.  There is [some documentation here](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/pom.html).  Your problem may be a network error in retrieving the external dependencies.  Also I noticed the task is parameterized with `maven.repo.local`, which is your `$HOME/.m2/repository` directory. Try checking if Maven created it yet, what permissions are like your `$HOME`, what's in the directory, etc.  Try also running ant with the `-v` and/or `-d` options for more debug output.

Comment: Thank you again. It was a yum upgrade problem, see revised question. Maven still didn't build due to an error in their xml file. But that is clearly their problem, not mine. I'll see if I can file a bug report with them.